# runOnUiThread from service to Activity

Tags: android, android-service

I have a method "send()" that send values to the server and then get response 0 or 1 from the server. then i want to active a method that check if its 0 or 1 and then i want to active a method that on MainActivity that called from the service.

**this is the service code**

```
    public class SendThreadCommunication extends Thread {
private final static String TAG = "SendThreadCommunication";
private final int READ_TIMEOUT = 100000;
private final int CONNECTION_TINEOUT = 100000;
private Looper myLooper;
private int mResponseCode;
private String mData = "";

private final ServerRequest req;
// private RegisterUser user;
private static String ans;

public SendThreadCommunication(ServerRequest req) {

    this.req = req;
}

public String readWebData(InputStream stream) {

    String line = "";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }
    return buffer.toString();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        send();
       // evaluateDataAndRespondToFragment(mData);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void send() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    OutputStream mOutputStream = null;
    BufferedWriter mWriter = null;

    List<NameValuePair> mParameters = req.getParameters();

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        Looper.prepare();
        url = new URL(req.returnRequestUrl());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TINEOUT);
        connection.setRequestMethod(Params.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        mOutputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        mWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mOutputStream, Params.UTF8));
        String sparams = URLEncodedUtils.format(mParameters, Params.UTF8);
        mWriter.write(sparams);
        mWriter.flush();

        mResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (mResponseCode > 203) {
            mData = readWebData(connection.getErrorStream());
            //this.req.getResponse().notGoodServerEroorr();
        } else {
            mData = readWebData(connection.getInputStream());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                if (mOutputStream != null)
                    mOutputStream.close();
                if (mWriter != null)
                    mWriter.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            connection.disconnect();
            evaluateDataAndRespondToFragment(mData);
            myLooper = Looper.myLooper();
            Looper.loop();
            myLooper.quit();

        }
    }
  }

private void evaluateDataAndRespondToFragment(String mData) {
    Listen lis = this.req.getResponse();

    if (mData.equals("1"))
        lis.good();
    else
        lis.notGood();

     if (mData.equals("0"))
     {
         lis.userGcmNotRegistered();
     }
    }
 }
```

---

this service code send to the server values and get response. the method "evaluateDataAndRespondToFragment" check if its 0 or 1 and then active the appropriate method. that method should trigger other method in the MainActivity.
i know that **runOnUiThread** handle this, but i dont know how to use it.
the method on the MainActivity change the UI.

**this is the MainActivity code**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, Listen {

private BroadcastReceiver statusReceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntent;
Sensor accelerometer;
SensorManager sm;
TextView acceleration;
SendValues sv;
int counter3 = 0;
int counter5 = 0;
int pastTime = 0;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


@Override
public void good() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "successful transfer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void notGood() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "UNsuccssful transfer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void userGcmNotRegistered() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "There is some problem, please register again to the App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

}
```

---

Here it should active one of the methods "good","not good"....
i know that **runOnUiThread** handle it but i dont know how to use it and where.
if anyone could tell me what to do i will appreciate.

Comment: You may wrap your code into AsyncTask which takes care of thread switching.

Answer (score 1):

A service doesn't have a **runOnUiThread** method, but you can use **intent** instead of.

Simply,

1. Add a **BroadcastReceiver** to your activity,
2. Add receiver to your **AndroidManifest.xml**,
3. Send **intent** from your service.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, Listen {

    private BroadcastReceiver statusReceiver;
    private IntentFilter mIntent;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    SensorManager sm;
    TextView acceleration;
    SendValues sv;
    int counter3 = 0;
    int counter5 = 0;
    int pastTime = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    statusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch(intent.getIntExtra("status", -1) {
                    case 1:
                        good();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        notGood();
                        break;
                    default:
                        userGcmNotRegistered();
                }
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver(statusReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.yourpackage.yourapp.GET_STATUS_INTENT");
        }


    @Override
    public void good() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "successful transfer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void notGood() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "UNsuccssful transfer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void userGcmNotRegistered() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "There is some problem, please register again to the App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

    }
```

A simple **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage.yourapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.yourpackage.yourapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.yourpackage.yourapp.GET_STATUS_INTENT">
                        </action>
                </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**evaluateDataAndRespondToFragment** method

```
private void evaluateDataAndRespondToFragment(String mData) {

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourpackage.yourapp.GET_STATUS_INTENT");
    intent.putExtra(status, mData);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
 }
```

Additionally you need to register/unregister within your activity's onResume/onPause methods.

Comment: i dont know why but in the "sendBroadcast" it gives me error. it says that i need to create method. do i need to implement something?

Comment: "cannot resolve method 'sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)'

Comment: `sendBroadcast()` is a methof of `Service`. The code you posted, however is not a `Service` it is a `Thread`. You will need to pass a reference to your `Service` into the `SendThreadCommunication` class when you instantiate it and then you can call `sendBroadcast()` on that reference.

Answer (score 0):

A bit **off topic**; but, Beremaran's answer is correct, you can't get the main thread from a service. However, runOnUiThread is a very important concept to know and use, to avoid blocking up your main thread. Blocking your main thread will cause the system to kill your app.

Let say you have some networking tasks to do, and you know that it can take some time to do that. Therefore you start a new Thread to do the slow work.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       messageFromSlowStuff = doSomeSlowStuff();
    };
}).start();
```

Now you might want to populate the UI with the new data *messageFromSlowStuff*, but you can't because it is only aloud from the main thread.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myTextView.setText(messageFromSlowStuff)
    }
});
```

If you are only updating a view as in the example above you can use View.post() an alternative to runOnUiThread.

```
myTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        messageFromSlowStuff = doSomeSlowStuff();
        myTextView.setText(messageFromSlowStuff);
    }
});
```

Here's the docs regarding View.post(): ["post reference"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))